# How to sum all of numeric columns in a table in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table that will have a variable number of columns based on my initial input. Is there a function to sum all the numeric columns of this table without specifying the name of each column?

Right now I have each column name hard coded in a proc sql command.

```
CREATE TABLE &new_table_name AS 
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN col1 = &state THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS month_01,
        SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = &state THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS month_02,
        SUM(CASE WHEN col3 = &state THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS month_03,
        SUM(CASE WHEN col4 = &state THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS month_04,
        SUM(CASE WHEN col5 = &state THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS month_05
);
```

Sample input would be like this:

```
name    m1  m2  m3  m4
aa      1   7   7   1
ab      2   4   2   
ac      1   1       
ad      1   3   1   1
ae      2   1   3
```

Then the sample output would be

```
name    m1  m2  m3  m4
        7   16  13  2
```

Comment: If you dont have the names, you need build a dynamic query.

Comment: Post sample data, in/out. I wonder if this shouldn't be a proc transpose. Your code seems unrelated to the stated question. You can't use variable lists in PROC SQL.

Comment: The matrix I'm trying to do the sum on is a post transpose data set.

Comment: Why are you not using PROC MEANS or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `PROC MEANS`.  Or really any summarization proc.

```
data have;
infile datalines missover;
input name $ m1  m2  m3  m4;
datalines;
aa      1   7   7   1
ab      2   4   2   
ac      1   1       
ad      1   3   1   1
ae      2   1   3   
;;;;
run;

proc means data=have;
  output out=want sum=;
run;
```

And the `class` statement would let you group by state or whatever.  `WHERE` also works fine in `PROC MEANS` to filter.

Leaving the `var` statement off calls for all numeric variables, or you can put in a `var` statement to limit, such as

```
var m1-m4;
```

as Reeza notes in comments.

Comment: In addition to Joe's answer you can use variable shortcuts in procs such as m1-m4 or m: (all variables starting with m).